# Using DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea to draw a solid color dialog with standard non-client controls

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog, dwm

I'm trying to create a dialog that looks more or less like this:

[image]

So in other words, I'd like it to be one solid color, with the seamless non-client area, and standard-looking non-client controls (close, minimize, etc.).

I imagine that that particular dialog uses some very custom rendering and custom controls, but I'm trying to achieve a similar effect using `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` and the techniques described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/customframe).  So in other words, I'd like to preserve the standard non-client controls provided by Windows (close, minimize etc.), and avoid having to draw them myself using `DrawThemeBackground`.

The first thing I don't understand is about [having to paint the window black](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/customframe#extending-the-client-frame) in order to see the extended non-client area.  Does that mean that, even if the dialog itself is white or gray via `WM_CTLCOLORDLG`, you need to handle `WM_PAINT` in the dialog to paint certain areas black?

And then my second question is how to actually paint the non-client area white (while still preserving the standard non-client controls).

Thanks for any input or guidance on how to accomplish this.  By the way, I tried the sample provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43819334/15025873), but that doesn't include the non-client controls (close, minimize, etc.).

Comment: Can this [custom-chrome project](https://github.com/oberth/custom-chrome) which  preserves the standard non-client controls provided by Windows and paints on the "non-client" area help you?

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'll take a look.