# How can I remove a window's non-client area completely?

Tags: c++, winapi, nonclient-area

**I need a window featuring no title bar, none of the control boxes, no system menu, and no frames (all that functionality is provided with separate controls).**

I suspect that this should be possible to do with `CreateWindowExA`'s window styles argument `dwStyle` and possibly `lpWindowName`, as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-styles

This is how the arguments look like originally:

```
HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
    0,                              // Optional window styles.
    CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class.
    L"",                            // No window name (title text).
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style.

    // Size and position.
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

    NULL,       // Parent window.
    NULL,       // Menu.
    hInstance,  // Instance handle.
    NULL        // Additional application data.
);
```

However, in `dwStyle`, the normal window style `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` is defined as

```
WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX
```

with `WS_OVERLAPPED` being `0x00000000L`.

Simply providing 0 and omitting the rest doesn't work, as also the documentation implies: "The window is an overlapped window. An overlapped window has a title bar and a border."

(The funny thing is, I am perfectly able to do this task in VB.NET (and even in VB6) by setting the `ControlBox` property to `False` and then by removing the titlebar using `Text = ""`, so I strongly suspect that when possible in VB...)

**How would I do my task in C++?**

---

Just in case the `WindowProc` is needed in order to process a different message, here it is in its minimalistic version:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;

        case WM_PAINT:
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            return 0;

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

(Compiling with VS 2017.)

Comment: WS_POPUP may work for you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-styles

Comment: @RetiredNinja, unfortunately, it doesn't. Probably I should also show my WindowProc, in case I do not catch a needed message. Updating this now.

Comment: As @RetiredNinja pointed out, the decoration for a borderless/frameless window should be `WS_POPUP`. If I remind correctly, the default windows class generated by VS2017 set the background color to `(COLOR_WINDOW + 1)`, and you are painting a rect with color `(COLOR_WINDOW + 1)`...

Comment: Use the Spy++ utility to see what style flags are used, mapping of the style flags is not very intuitive after 32 years.  VB.NET uses style = WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_TABSTOP, exstyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT and a NULL for the window text.  Or in other words, it is WS_CLIPCHILDREN that actually helps to avoid WS_OVERLAPPED :)  Why WS_POPUP produces an invisible window is not intuitive to me, it is not CW_USEDEFAULT.

Comment: `WS_POPUP` normally works. It doesn't work in your case, because you still have `CW_USEDEFAULT` arguments, which are only valid for overlapped windows. _"if CW_USEDEFAULT is specified for a pop-up or child window, nWidth and nHeight are set to zero."_

Comment: [Another technique](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43818022/7571258), which removes the border but keeps the drop shadow.

Comment: @zett42, thanks. When I replace position and size with, say, 100, 100 and 100, 100, it works like intended. If you bother to transform your comment into an answer, I'd gladly accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The non-client area of a top-level window can be removed by using only the `WS_POPUP` style:

```
HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
    0,                              // Optional window styles.
    CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class.
    L"",                            // No window name (title text).
    WS_POPUP,                       // Window style.

    // Size and position.
    100, 100, 400, 300,

    NULL,       // Parent window.
    NULL,       // Menu.
    hInstance,  // Instance handle.
    NULL        // Additional application data.
);
```

Note that `CW_USEDEFAULT` for size and position is only valid for overlapped windows. For popup windows you have to be explicit.

Depending on your use case, the technique described by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43819334/7571258) might be better suitable. Using the DWM API, it allows you to remove the non-client area, but **keep the drop shadow** to make the window stand out better from the background.